# In bs4 get text between elements

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

HTML Source:

```
<script type="text/javascript">window._sharedData = {"activity_counts":null,"config":{"csrf_token":"P8DvqEB5AxkRuWyoNWhrZ3Bi2scbrVm9","viewer":null},"supports_es6":true,"country_code":"NL","language_code":"en","locale":"en_US","entry_data":{"ProfilePage":[{"logging_page_id":"profilePage_4469324900","show_suggested_profiles":false,"graphql":{"user":{"biography":"","blocked_by_viewer":false,"country_block":false,"external_url":null,"external_url_linkshimmed":null,"edge_followed_by":{"count":143},"followed_by_viewer":false,"edge_follow":{"count":43},"follows_viewer":false,"full_name":"\u0627\u062c\u0627\u0631\u0647 \u0648\u06cc\u0644\u0627 \u062f\u0631 \u06af\u0631\u062f\u0646\u0647 ..................  ;</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var docElement = document.documentElement;
    var classRE = new RegExp('(^|\\s)no-js(\\s|$)');
    var className = docElement.className;
    docElement.className = className.replace(classRE, '$1js$2');
  })();
</script>
```

Now i want output show **JUST** every thing after `window._sharedData =`

Output:

```
{"activity_counts":null,"config":{"csrf_token":"P8DvqEB5AxkRuWyoNWhrZ3Bi2scbrVm9","viewer":null},"supports_es6":true,"count .......`
```

Here is my code :

```
url = 'https://www.instagram.com/mehran_eblaghi/'
s = requests.session()
soup = bs(s.get(url).text, 'html.parser').findAll('script')
print(soup)
```

Comment: Hi, please show your code, and explain which part of does not work for you.

Comment: Have you already parsed the source by using beautifulsoup, searched for the first script tag and then taken its text as a starting point?

Comment: @JonClements yes but is parsed all script

Comment: use [get_text()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text)

Comment: That's what `findAll` does... if it's the first script you're after then you can do something like `soup = bs(s.get(url).text, 'html.parser')` then work with that object, `data = soup.select_one('script').text.partition(' = ')[2]` might work (untested) ?

Comment: @JonClements its Second script .

Comment: So it'd be `soup.select('script')[1]...` then similar to above...

Comment: @JonClements i used 'data = soup.select('script')[1].text.partition(' = ')[2]' but output is empty .

Comment: @AndyPeterson elaborated on the answer a bit showingif found/not found logic and how to then load the string found as json data so it's actually usable. Hope that helps... (I imagine that's what you're wanting to do anyway...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use bs4 to find the first script tag whose text starts with what you're looking for and then take the text content of that and split the start of it, eg:

```
import json
import requests
import bs4

key = 'window._sharedData = '

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')
script_tag = soup.find('script', text=lambda L: L and L.startswith(key))
if script_tag:
    # raw string of data in script
    text_data = script_tag.text.partition(key)[2]
    # remove the trailing ; and you've json data... interpret as such
    data = json.loads(text_data.rstrip(';\n'))
else:
    # didn't find a match - up to you what to do here...
```

If you managed to find the relevant script tag, then `data` will be a Python dictionary of:

```
{'activity_counts': None,
 'config': {'csrf_token': '1Srrhc6GQmmC19TdM3nLFsDOORtJMpCj', 'viewer': None},
 'supports_es6': False,
 'country_code': 'GB',
 'language_code': 'en',
 'locale': 'en_US',
 'entry_data': {'ProfilePage': [{'logging_page_id': 'profilePage_4469324900',
    'show_suggested_profiles': False,
    'graphql': {'user': {'biography': '',
      'blocked_by_viewer': False,
      'country_block': False,
      'external_url': None,
      'external_url_linkshimmed': None,
      'edge_followed_by': {'count': 143},
      'followed_by_viewer': False,
      'edge_follow': {'count': 43},
      'follows_viewer': False,
      'full_name': 'اجاره ویلا در گردنه حیران',
      'has_channel': False,
      'has_blocked_viewer': False,
      'highlight_reel_count': 0,
      'has_requested_viewer': False,
      'id': '4469324900',
      'is_business_account': False,
      'is_private': False,
      'is_verified': False,
      'edge_mutual_followed_by': {'count': 0, 'edges': []},
      'profile_pic_url': 'https://scontent-lht6-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/ee763d48bb0c35ac0c6aa22dc1e2ed08/5C31C768/t51.2885-19/s150x150/15876073_1641186492851073_2628164662507601920_n.jpg',
      'profile_pic_url_hd': 'https://scontent-lht6-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/fd5c97116848cf46ddf24f8ac8d1fd7e/5C35B210/t51.2885-19/s320x320/15876073_1641186492851073_2628164662507601920_n.jpg',
      'requested_by_viewer': False,
      'username': 'mehran_eblaghi',
      'connected_fb_page': None,
      'edge_owner_to_timeline_media': {'count': 2,
       'page_info': {'has_next_page': False,
        'end_cursor': 'AQBnocogeHdSL1DSSxRdiYR4D1RguUeEj5Ap1do1KIy4U_NutZIe9ZCyRpDExD4TL9k'},
       'edges': [{'node': {'__typename': 'GraphImage',
          'id': '1429655015362664538',
          'edge_media_to_caption': {'edges': [{'node': {'text': 'درصورت نیاز به ویلاتماس بگیرید 09112815125'}}]},
          'shortcode': 'BPXJ6luDBha',
          'edge_media_to_comment': {'count': 10},
          'comments_disabled': False,
          'taken_at_timestamp': 1484648180,
          'dimensions': {'height': 1080, 'width': 1080},
          'display_url': 'https://scontent-lht6-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/abeb67556e5e2166e497cc779e99fab2/5C33A30D/t51.2885-15/e35/14597426_594812037376264_3725484886300033024_n.jpg',
          'edge_liked_by': {'count': 42},
          'edge_media_preview_like': {'count': 42},
          'gating_info': None,
          'media_preview': 'ACoqZEv32OQcHHpViMrKoJxkE59cVnFC7HB6epP+NSBGhXdkc8e/5+lNRYc0UaYiBO7J9aR3DDg4IOCaoR3IOFwcr1x0wf8AGkF0vJCHB75POP5UrNF3XyNBpARwQe1VN+OKiEqA5AIbr+Hr0q7tVud/Xn7p/wAahptj0RnKcEkVKXwMY/lTEbHNSbt3OK6rbadF1OaMrXXNZ3elr/oN345A5/xpxk56cGoy5JpBKR9KVutvxKUntzO3+H0/p9SSRz0x/wDqqrg1P5mRj161HVxVuljKcru6lf8ACw8DNH61KANo+lMIFGvRrbt/wSLq7unu+v8AwBhIHamnHYfqKdimEClZ919z/wAwutrfl/kKKKYAKkqlfr+Vv1Ynbof/2Q==',
          'owner': {'id': '4469324900'},
          'thumbnail_src': 'https://scontent-lht6-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/a50ea8ec7e91454bc0b981b9a347c2b9/5C2CDBE8/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/s640x640/14597426_594812037376264_3725484886300033024_n.jpg',
          'thumbnail_resources': [{'src': 'https://scontent-lht6-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/8ecae5da8cdf4f981a29ec7a0c6b0a08/5C30AF4F/t51.2885-15/e35/s150x150/14597426_594812037376264_3725484886300033024_n.jpg',
            'config_width': 150,
            'config_height': 150},
           {'src': 'https://scontent-lht6-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/fe3689ac4d9165c32369e8fc460f0040/5C187505/t51.2885-15/e35/s240x240/14597426_594812037376264_3725484886300033024_n.jpg',
            'config_width': 240,
            'config_height': 240},
           {'src': 'https://scontent-lht6-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/be7a47d6b422add7f77d597c0eecd21e/5C31FBBF/t51.2885-15/e35/s320x320/14597426_594812037376264_3725484886300033024_n.jpg',
            'config_width': 320,
            'config_height': 320},
           {'src': 'https://scontent-lht6-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/2f6d7c80500d9d56f940be6ffa0e8e9a/5C1568E5/t51.2885-15/e35/s480x480/14597426_594812037376264_3725484886300033024_n.jpg',
            'config_width': 480,
            'config_height': 480},
           {'src': 'https://scontent-lht6-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/a50ea8ec7e91454bc0b981b9a347c2b9/5C2CDBE8/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/s640x640/14597426_594812037376264_3725484886300033024_n.jpg',
            'config_width': 640,
            'config_height': 640}],
          'is_video': False,
          'accessibility_caption': None}},
        {'node': {'__typename': 'GraphImage',
          'id': '1429628539162724247',
          'edge_media_to_caption': {'edges': []},
          'shortcode': 'BPXD5T1jgeX',
          'edge_media_to_comment': {'count': 3},
          'comments_disabled': False,
          'taken_at_timestamp': 1484645024,
          'dimensions': {'height': 1080, 'width': 1080},
          'display_url': 'https://scontent-lht6-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/b48766cc9da8d14904f702a927884f5b/5C2B24EA/t51.2885-15/e35/16110374_198276563977954_7548368730246348800_n.jpg',
          'edge_liked_by': {'count': 42},
          'edge_media_preview_like': {'count': 42},
          'gating_info': None,
          'media_preview': 'ACoqdDpYeEP0J5wTSHR2C5yPzP8AhVn7YVi45xgYNWbWbzjtII4z1BFVzMjQpxacigHILZ6c/wD1qr6jaFDuwMH0rdBjDYGMjg5pJYVkXDcjNF9bkOCvzLc4dhim5rR1K3EEmByD0rNq7miNRmLIQOScVYsJGik+YEbhgfnn+VY4ncd6kSaR+nJH6etZhaxqyXa/PzyW4/Opri+/dqqn+77dqwZFZTyOvI96aZGHB4x7UrBa5PevvlJ69P5VVp5DPz1pm0+hqwL6wRZ5GB7k/wD6qsRwRxncuc/Wq6E0McEY4osTctCJGYM7EsvTt/jUhhiJ3MN59W5/+tUAozSsFywWUYCgY/pTOKhYZGaQGixLP//Z',
          'owner': {'id': '4469324900'},
          'thumbnail_src': 'https://scontent-lht6-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/d37f58bf9a6bcbe17242a7e0b233c5c0/5C331E0F/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/s640x640/16110374_198276563977954_7548368730246348800_n.jpg',
          'thumbnail_resources': [{'src': 'https://scontent-lht6-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/f14bd4b53c62c2fe56ba88f1a3ab85cf/5C1DC3A8/t51.2885-15/e35/s150x150/16110374_198276563977954_7548368730246348800_n.jpg',
            'config_width': 150,
            'config_height': 150},
           {'src': 'https://scontent-lht6-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/616bc4d9abe790d1c9e06dbb22e7b43f/5C266AE2/t51.2885-15/e35/s240x240/16110374_198276563977954_7548368730246348800_n.jpg',
            'config_width': 240,
            'config_height': 240},
           {'src': 'https://scontent-lht6-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/09d6473c69ad0b4e493f05c6d3aad9a4/5C205958/t51.2885-15/e35/s320x320/16110374_198276563977954_7548368730246348800_n.jpg',
            'config_width': 320,
            'config_height': 320},
           {'src': 'https://scontent-lht6-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/e5d6902499831040caded69325585dfc/5C350A02/t51.2885-15/e35/s480x480/16110374_198276563977954_7548368730246348800_n.jpg',
            'config_width': 480,
            'config_height': 480},
           {'src': 'https://scontent-lht6-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/d37f58bf9a6bcbe17242a7e0b233c5c0/5C331E0F/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/s640x640/16110374_198276563977954_7548368730246348800_n.jpg',
            'config_width': 640,
            'config_height': 640}],
          'is_video': False,
          'accessibility_caption': None}}]},
      'edge_saved_media': {'count': 0,
       'page_info': {'has_next_page': False, 'end_cursor': None},
       'edges': []},
      'edge_media_collections': {'count': 0,
       'page_info': {'has_next_page': False, 'end_cursor': None},
       'edges': []}}},
    'felix_onboarding_video_resources': {'mp4': '/static/videos/felix-onboarding/onboardingVideo.mp4/9d16838ca7f9.mp4',
     'poster': '/static/images/felix-onboarding/onboardingVideoPoster.png/8fdba7cf2120.png'}}]},
 'gatekeepers': {'cb': True,
  'sf': True,
  'ld': True,
  'seo': True,
  'seoht': True,
  'saa': True,
  'phone_qp': True},
 'knobs': {'acct:ntb': 0, 'cb': 0, 'captcha': 0},
 'qe': {'form_navigation_dialog': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'cred_man': {'g': 'test', 'p': {'use_on_landing': 'true'}},
  'iab': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'app_upsell_li': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'app_upsell': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'stale_fix': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'profile_header_name': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'bc3l': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'direct_conversation_reporting': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'general_reporting': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'reporting': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'acc_recovery_link': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'notif': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'fb_unlink': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'mobile_stories_doodling': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'show_copy_link': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'mobile_logout': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'p_edit': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  '404_as_react': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'acc_recovery': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'collections': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'comment_ta': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'su': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'disc_ppl': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'ebd_ul': {'g': 'launch', 'p': {'is_enabled': 'true'}},
  'ebdsim_li': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'ebdsim_lo': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'empty_feed': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'bundles': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'exit_story_creation': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'appsell': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'imgopt': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'follow_button': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'loggedout': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'loggedout_upsell': {'g': 'control_without_new_loggedout_upsell_content_03_15_18',
   'p': {'has_new_loggedout_upsell_content': 'false'}},
  'msisdn': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'bg_sync': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'onetaplogin': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'login_poe': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'private_lo': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'profile_tabs': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'push_notifications': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'reg': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'reg_vp': {'g': 'test_group_1', 'p': {'hide_value_prop': 'true'}},
  'report_media': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'report_profile': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'scroll_log': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'sidecar_swipe': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'su_universe': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'stale': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'stories_lo': {'g': 'test_05_01', 'p': {'location': 'true'}},
  'stories': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'tp_pblshr': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'video': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'gdpr_eu_tos': {'g': 'control_05_01',
   'p': {'gdpr_required': 'true',
    'eu_new_user_flow': 'age_two_button',
    'tos_version': 'eu'}},
  'gdpr_row_tos': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'fd_gr': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'felix': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'felix_clear_fb_cookie': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'felix_creation_duration_limits': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'felix_creation_enabled': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'felix_creation_fb_crossposting': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'felix_creation_fb_crossposting_v2': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'felix_creation_validation': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'felix_creation_video_upload': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'felix_early_onboarding': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'unfollow_confirm': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'profile_enhance_li': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'profile_enhance_lo': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'phone_confirm': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'comment_enhance': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'mweb_topical_explore': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'web_nametag': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'image_downgrade': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'image_downgrade_lite': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'follow_all_fb': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'lite_direct_upsell': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'web_loggedout_noop': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'stories_video_preload': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'lite_stories_video_preload': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'a2hs_heuristic_uc': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'a2hs_heuristic_non_uc': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'web_hashtag': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'header_scroll': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'rout': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'websr': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'web_lo_follow': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'web_share': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'lite_rating': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'web_embeds_share': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'web_share_lo': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'web_embeds_logged_out': {'g': 'test_comment_input',
   'p': {'show_comment_input': 'true'}},
  'sl': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'reg_nux': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'web_datasaver_mode': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'lite_datasaver_mode': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
  'lite_video_upload': {'g': '', 'p': {}}},
 'hostname': 'www.instagram.com',
 'platform': 'web',
 'rhx_gis': 'b9d7a25d3e0772990918069a0652bc21',
 'nonce': 'E+077618aJD12ZjcMWUynA==',
 'zero_data': {},
 'rollout_hash': '2502ae2429f4',
 'bundle_variant': 'base',
 'probably_has_app': False}
```

Comment: to convert it to json it got me error   ` File "search.py", line 39, in <module>
    get_url()
  File "search.py", line 16, in get_url
    data = json.loads(text_data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 342, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 10631 (char 10630)`

Comment: @Andy did you include the `.rstrip(';')` ?

Comment: ` data = json.loads(text_data).rstrip(';') `  i add here but not work .

Comment: @Andy the line should be as per in this answer which is `data = json.loads(text_data.rstrip(';'))` :)

Comment: @Andy okay... copy and paste this answer, add the `url = ...` to the address you're using and then run it from scratch - you should be fine...

Comment: @Andy make it `data = json.loads(text_data.rstrip(';\n'))`... just in case there's extra trailing new lines... (have updated answer accordingly)